# How to get the public keys for the whole certificate chain using openssl?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I tried the following command to get the certificate and save it as text file:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.domain.com:443 -showcerts > file.txt
```

Then I used the following to get the public key:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in file.txt
```

The public key I get is the one associated with certificate no.1 . What can I do in order to get the whole chain public keys ? and is there a better method I can use to improve what I'm doing (i.e: if there is a way to get the public keys for the whole certificate chain in one step instead of the two steps I'm doing).

Comment: Why? You don't need the public keys of the signers.

Comment: `x509 -modulus` gives you _part_ -- not all -- of an _RSA_ publickey, and fails entirely for other key types. For example stackoverflow (and the rest of stackexchange) now uses an EC(DSA) cert from LetsEncrypt, whose intermediate E1 _and_ root X2 also use EC(DSA), although for now they still bridge to root X1 and obsolete root DST X3 which are RSA.

Answer (score 1):

From

```
openssl s_client -connect www.domain.com:443 -showcerts > file.txt
```

You'll get a list of certificate as you described. If you copy these certificates into files named *cert1.pem*, *cert2.pem*, etc, where each cert looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then you can print the public keys of each certificate in the chain like so:

```
openssl x509 -in cert1.pem -noout -pubkey
openssl x509 -in cert2.pem -noout -pubkey
...
```

Comment: If on Unix or otherwise using a capable shell (e.g. cygwin) you can do `openssl s_client ... -showcerts | while openssl x509 -noout -pubkey; do :; done` -- or you might want a little more data such as `openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -pubkey`.